# If the number of elements in a group $G$ of order $289$ is $n\geq 273$ then $G$ is not cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ a finite group  and $n$ the number of elements in $G$ of order $289$. Show that if $n\geq 273$ then $G$ is not cyclic.

Comment: How many elements of order 289 are there in a cyclic group?

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is cyclic and has one element of order $289$ then it contains exactly one subgroup of order $289=17^2$, it follows that in $G$ there are exactly $\phi(289)=17\times 16=272$ elements of order $289 $. This contradicts the asumption.

Comment: Well, no: a cyclic group contains **at most** 272 elements of order $289$, for it may well not contain any!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, you are right, in a cyclic group, either there is no elements of order 289 or there are 272. The assumption $n\ge 273$ implies that there is one element of order 289 in the group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez you are wrong! If $G$ is cyclic of order $n$ then for every $m$ that divides $n$ you have *exactly* $\phi(m)$ elements in $G$ of order $m$, where $\phi$ is the Euler function.

Comment: @OmranKouba your answer is right!